# How to find the latest tag matching a specific pattern in Mercurial (Hg)

Tags: tags, mercurial

I know how to do this in git for the glob-style tag pattern ros/* with:

```
git describe --abbrev=0 --tags --match 'ros/*'
```

What is the equivalent hg command?

I know I can get the latest tag with either of the following command:

```
hg log --rev . --template {latesttag}
```

Answer (score 2):

The hg latesttag function actually accepts a pattern. So the equivalent command is:

```
hg log -r . --template "{latesttag(r're:ros/.*')}"
```

Comment: plain pattern `{latesttag('re:REGEXP')}` will work also

Answer (score 2):

You can also use revset for the same result

`hg log -r "last(tag('re:ros/.*'))"`